# Do Nigerians need a Transit visa at Dublin airport?

Tags: visas, transit, nigerian-citizens, dublin, common-travel-area

A Nigerian Nationality My wife and kids are traveling from South Africa to Canada, and I booked British Airways for 2 layover tickets. One ticket is from South Africa to London, and the second is from Dublin to Toronto. They do not have any checked bags, so they do not need to collect there bags. only hand luggage in hand. Their tickets is 09:00 and 13:20 same day, which is still within a range

Does he require any type of visa to transit through Dublin?

Comment: How are they getting between London and Dublin?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183422/question-regarding-transit-visa-at-dublin-airport?noredirect=1#comment468032_183422 that is the link of the question

Comment: That is the link to this question, not the other one, and please edit all information into this question.

Answer (score 1):

> Does he require any type of visa to transit through Dublin? **Yes.**

According to [Irish Immigration](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/), Nigeria is a *transit visa required* country.

Note also the information [here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1143004/Transit.pdf) regarding the implications of the UK’s Immigration Rules relating to TWOV in the Common Travel Area. Effectively, London to Dublin is considered a *domestic* flight and so immigration controls apply in London [Transit query Delhi-London-Dublin-Toronto](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180049/transit-query-delhi-london-dublin-toronto)

Comment: Thanks to everybody who reached out regarding this question, What I later did was change my flight to one transit which is only at Heartow Airport to Pearson Airport in Toronto, instead of going to Dublin to transit Moreover I didn't have the time to request for transit visa for Dublin